# How Do I Find Out The Most Active Time Of The Day In Sales Data In Python?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, time-series

I've the following sample dataset:

[image]

I need to find out the most active time of the day when sales are happening (by the hour or hour segments, any would do fine) from the column of 'Transaction Date'. I also need to find out the most active day (as in Monday, Tuesday, etc.), from the same column.

Now, my initial approach was to first rejig the **Order_Details** dataframe I'd created for the dataset to be more accomodating as:

```
Order_Details['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(Order_Details['Transaction Date'])
Order_Details['Hour'] = (Order_Details['Time']).dt.hour

Order_Details['Hour'].unique()
```

And then I decided to obtain a Series as:

```
timemost = Order_Details['Hour'].value_counts()
```

But it is here that I hit an obstacle. Whilst this **timemost** series does return the most frequent hour of the day by the count, it does so in a sorted order, and I need to have two separate lists -- one for the frequency of occurence and the other for the hour itself, where frequency is sorted by hour and not the other way around. And finally, I intend to plot it as line/bar chart, whatever may be applicable.

What should I do to improve this and get the desired result?

Comment: post the data inline, instead of images, to help reproduce.

Comment: Also, please show us your desired output for the sample data input you provide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, it is more encouraging to help if the data is easier to be reproduced.

Order_Details dataframe:

```
Name                     Email                                     Product    Transaction Date
PERSON_1        PERSON_1@gmail.com                                  PRODUCT_75 2021-03-01 00:47:00
PERSON_2 PERSON_2@tataprojects.com                                  PRODUCT_75 2021-03-01 02:04:00
PERSON_3        PERSON_3@gmail.com                                  PRODUCT_63 2021-03-01 09:10:00
PERSON_4        PERSON_4@gmail.com                                  PRODUCT_63 2021-03-01 09:49:00
PERSON_5        PERSON_5@gmail.com PRODUCT_34,PRODUCT_86,PRODUCT_57,PRODUCT_89 2021-03-01 10:56:00
PERSON_6        PERSON_6@gmail.com PRODUCT_34,PRODUCT_66,PRODUCT_58,PRODUCT_83 2021-03-01 11:06:00
PERSON_7        PERSON_7@gmail.com                                  PRODUCT_75 2021-03-01 12:02:00
PERSON_8        PERSON_8@gmail.com PRODUCT_63,PRODUCT_90,PRODUCT_27,PRODUCT_5S 2021-03-01 12:31:00
PERSON_9      PERSON_9@outlook.com                                  PRODUCT_26 2021-03-01 12:51:00
PERSON_10       PERSON_10@gmail.com                                  PRODUCT_63 2021-03-01 12:52:00
PERSON_11       PERSON_11@gmail.com                                  PRODUCT_63 2021-03-01 13:15:00
PERSON_12       PERSON_12@gmail.com                        PRODUCT_5,PRODUCT_34 2021-03-01 13:37:00
PERSON_13       PERSON_13@gmail.com                       PRODUCT_84,PRODUCT_27 2021-03-01 14:17:00
PERSON_14       PERSON_14@gmail.com                                  PRODUCT_27 2021-03-01 14:27:00
PERSON_15       PERSON_15@gmail.com                                  PRODUCT_25 2021-03-01 14:37:00
PERSON_16       PERSON_16@gmail.com                                  PRODUCT_75 2021-03-01 14:56:00
PERSON_17       PERSON_17@gmail.com                                  PRODUCT_84 2021-03-01 15:03:00
PERSON_18       PERSON_18@gmail.com                                  PRODUCT_34 2021-03-01 15:08:00
PERSON 19       PERSON 19@gmail.com                                  PRODUCT 85 2021-03-01 15:48:00
```

You can create the 'Hour' column straightforward:

```
Order_Details['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(Order_Details['Transaction Date']).dt.hour
```

I don't think that calling the 'unique' method will change anything

sorting by index:

```
timemost = Order_Details['Time'].value_counts().sort_index()

0     1
2     1
9     2
10    1
11    1
12    4
13    2
14    4
15    3
```

the line plot:

```
line = timemost.plot.line()
```

and finally, to show you have to import the 'maplotlib.pyplot' module:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.show()
```

[image: most frequent hour]